# GnuTLS test 'chat' equivalent of OpenSSL s_client s_server

Tags: ssl, pgp, openssl

How can I set up a test encrypted "chat" with GnuTLS, equivalent to the OpenSSL s_client and s_server using GPG credentials?

I would like to tell GnuTLS-serv and -cli to use keys generated with GPG using (example [here](http://gnutls.org/manual/html_node/gnutls_002dserv-Invocation.html) ):

```
gpg --gen-key
gpg -a --export 5D1D14D8 > openpgp-server.txt
gpg --export 5D1D14D8 > openpgp-server.bin
gpg --export-secret-keys 5D1D14D8 > openpgp-server-key.bin
gpg -a --export-secret-keys 5D1D14D8 > openpgp-server-key.txt
```

Is it correct to launch server using a command like this:
`gnutls-serv --echo --pgpkeyfile openpgp-server-key.txt --pgpcertfile openpgp-server.txt`?

Also, what arguments needs GnuTLS-cli to connect?

Comment: I'm not asking about how to use the GnuTLS' APIs in a certain programming language. I'm asking how to use `gnutls-serv` and `gnutls-cli` in the same way you can use OpenSSL's `s_client` and `s_server`, that is to create a cryptographic test tunnel between server and client. It's about Cryptography not about Programming or Linux since GnuTLS is exactly like OpenSSL an implementation of SSL and TLS protocols... (there are similar questions like mine, for example: [link](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/11310/with-openssl-and-ecdhe-how-to-show-the-actual-curve-being-used) ).

Comment: Hi. I would like to tell him to use keys generated with GPG (see above) in a test "chat" between `gnutls-cli` and `gnutls-serv`. Thanks in advance.